# How to create a reference variable in c++?

Tags: c++

I have created a reference variable but I can't get the expected result. The reference variable is printing some hexadecimal numbers like >>>0x6ffe20

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main(){
      string food = "pizza";
      string &meal = food;
      cout << food << endl;
      cout << &meal << endl;
      cout << "The &meal and food variable are same " << endl;
    
}
```

Comment: `cout << &meal << endl;` on right hand side `&` means `address of`. You already have a reference, and it doesn't need to be taken the address of

Comment: This is explained in any beginner level [c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 0):

Just do a `cout << meal;`

With `cout << &meal;` you are printing the memory address of the reference. The & means address.

Comment: In an expression `&` means address-of, in a declaration it means reference. I guess that's where the confusion comes from.

Comment: Actually it's not the memory address of the reference, but the address of the referenced variable.

Comment: Well, as the reference is just a another name for the same variable, the address of the reference and the address of the referenced variable are the same!